# Solr ignoring configSetBaseDir

Tags: java, solr, apache-zookeeper

I have solr.xml looking like this...

```
<solr>
        <str name="configSetBaseDir">${configSetBaseDir:/opt/configsets}</str>
        <solrcloud>
```

configSetBaseDir is pointing to a valid directory with a presumably valid config set. It's not getting loaded into ZooKeeper when solr restarts. Is there something wrong or missing here that it needs besides configSetBaseDir?